# Should I Replace Multiple Float Columns with a BLOB?

Tags: sql-server, performance, blob, insert-into, poeaa

How would a single BLOB column in SQL Server compare (performance wise), to ~20 REAL columns (20 x 32-bit floats)?

I remember Martin Fowler recommending using BLOBs for persisting large object graphs (in Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture) to remove multiple joins in queries, but does it make sense to do something like this for a table with 20 fixed columns (which are never used in queries)?

This table is updated really often, around 100 times per second, and `INSERT` statements get rather large with all the columns specified in the query.

I presume the first answer is going to be "profile it yourself", but I'd like to know if someone already has experience with this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fully speak to the performance of the `SELECT`, you'll need to test that, but I highly doubt it will cause any performance issues there because you wouldn't be reading any more data than before. However, in regards to the `INSERT`, you should see a performance gain (of what size I'm unsure), because there will **likely** not be any statistical indexes to update. Of course that depends on **a lot** of settings but I'm just throwing my opinion out there. This question is pretty subjective and not near enough information is available to truly tell you if you will see performance issues surrounding the change.

Now, in practice I'm going to say, leave it be unless you're seeing real performance issues. Further, if you're seeing real performance issues, analyze those before choosing this type of solution, there are probably other ways to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you should not, if you have not found out that this is critical to meet your performance requirements.

If you store it in one blob you need to recalculate your whole database if you make any change to the object structure (like adding or removing a column). If you keep multiple columns your future database refactorings and deployments will be much easier.